# Categorising transactions in past 90 days

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table where the columns are:

- Transaction_id(`T_id`): Distinct id generated for each transactions
- Date(`Dt`): Date of Transaction
- account-id(`Ac_id`): The id from which the transaction is done
- Org_id(`O_id`): It is the id given to the organizations. One organization can have multiple accounts thereby different account id can have the same org_id

Sample table:

| T_id | Dt | Ac_id | O_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 23/4/22 | 1 | A |
| 102 | 06/7/22 | 3 | C |
| 103 | 01/8/22 | 2 | A |
| 104 | 13/3/22 | 6 | B |

*The question is to mark the `o_id` where transactions are done in the past 90 days as 1 and others as 0

Output

| T_id | Dt. | Ac_id. | O_id | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 23/4/22 | 1 | A | 0 |
| 102 | 06/7/22 | 3 | C | 1 |
| 103 | 01/8/22 | 2 | A | 1 |
| 104 | 13/3/22 | 6 | B | 0 |

The query I am using is:

```
Select *,
Case when datediff('day', Dt, current_date()) between 0 and 90 then '1'
Else '0'
End as Mark
From Table1
```

Desired Output:

| T_id | Dt. | Ac_id. | O_id | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 23/4/22 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 102 | 06/7/22 | 3 | C | 1 |
| 103 | 01/8/22 | 2 | A | 1 |
| 104 | 13/3/22 | 6 | B | 0 |

- for `o_id` 'A' from the output the mark I want is 1 in all cases as one transaction is done past 90 days, irrespective of other transactions done prior to 90days.
- I have to join this out to another table so need all o_id where ever any one transaction is done in the past 90 days as '1'.

Please help me with it quickly.

Comment: Please provide the data in correct formatted table structure for understanding better.

Comment: while writing the question as well as in the draft also the table is showing, but after posting why the table is not showing I don't know.

Comment: @Sid, the markdown for the table was fine. For some reason if there's a line directly above table markdown it will not render the table properly. If you add a blank line above the table it fixes that.

Comment: Thanks @GregPavlik. Will keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The easisest approach is to compare date difference  of current date against windowed `MAX` partitioned by `o_id`:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE 
     WHEN DATEDIFF('day', (MAX(Dt) OVER(PARTITION BY o_id)), CURRENT_DATE()) <= 90 
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
  END AS Mark
FROM Tab;
```

---

Sample data:

```
ALTER SESSION SET DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(t_id INT,
                            Dt Date,
                            Ac_id INT,
                            O_id TEXT)
AS
SELECT 101,     '23/04/2022'    ,1  ,'A' UNION
SELECT 102,     '06/07/2022'    ,3  ,'C' UNION
SELECT 103,     '01/08/2022'    ,2  ,'A' UNION
SELECT 104,     '13/03/2022'    ,6  ,'B';
```

Output:

[image]

---

Snowflake supports natively [BOOLEAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-logical.html#boolean) data types so entire query could be just:

```
SELECT *,
 DATEDIFF('day', (MAX(Dt) OVER(PARTITION BY o_id)), CURRENT_DATE()) <= 90 AS Mark
FROM tab
```

Comment: I like this better - I was initially concerned that the window function would be executed for each row in the result set, but see that Snowflake's query optimizer runs it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subquery where you identify all the distinct o_id where there is a recent transaction, and use that to update the main result.

The subquery would be:

```
select o_id, dt from table1 
group by o_id
having datediff('day', max(Dt), current_date()) between 0 and 90;
```

Then your main query becomes:

```
 Select *,'1' as Mark
    From Tab
    where o_id in 
       (select x.o_id from (select o_id, max(Dt) 
        from tab 
        group by o_id
        having datediff('day', max(Dt), current_date()) between 0 and 90) x)
    union all
    select *,'0' as Mark
    from Tab
    where o_id not in 
        (select x.o_id from (select o_id, max(Dt) 
        from tab 
        group by o_id
        having datediff('day', max(Dt), current_date()) between 0 and 90) x);
```